# Markdown headers don't work inside spoiler tags

Tags: bug, markdown, spoilers

I discovered, while trying to edit a post using a spoiler block, that spoilers appear to interfere with Markdown heading syntax (hash(es) followed by text: `# header`), causing them to simply not render as a heading:

> # This should be a heading

> ### This too

Blockquotes don't have this problem:

> ## This should be a heading

> #### This too

Using the HTML heading tags `<hX>` instead of Markdown syntax yields some odd spacing, lots of unnecessary space appears above the heading, though the text itself renders correctly:

> ## This should be a heading

> #### This too

I know spoiler blocks can be a bit... finicky, since they're a custom syntax for SE, and I found posts referencing that a reduced set of markdown was possibly supported inside them. I just still expected to be able to work around it by using the HTML equivalent, which *also* seems to be partially broken.

Is this a bug? Or is it a by-design thing?

---

Some previous references (direct and indirect) to this phenomenon:

- [Spoilers don't format well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-format-well), MSE, *Dec 20 '11*
- [How to quote a question or answer as spoiler?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-to-quote-a-question-or-answer-as-spoiler/1190), Anime & Manga SE Meta, *Dec 26 '14*
- [Make Markdown syntax of blockquote and spoiler block consistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247447/make-markdown-syntax-of-blockquote-and-spoiler-block-consistent), MSE, *Jan 22 '15*
- [Embedding HTML into spoiler tags creates “odd” HTML?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261531/embedding-html-into-spoiler-tags-creates-odd-html/283598), MSE, *Jul 27 '15*

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-format-well) too.  Same problem at the end of the post.  You have to use <h3> tags.

Comment: This issue exists in the app, so I'm guessing it's been this way forever. Might check for an existing report.

Comment: @Ollie Managed to find [another, almost identical, post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247447/776523) to your linked.

Comment: I've noticed this problem before...can't think why I didn't report it.  The <h3> shortcut is a good one, though.

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes, I've read that post before.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't see your post edit.  Deleting.

Comment: See also: Embedding HTML in spoilers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283598/282094

Comment: @Catija See above. It seems you're right; this has been an issue since 2011.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Considering the age of that question and the persistence of the problem, I hope this gets some priority now.

Comment: The <h1> doesn't create odd spacing:  If you do the same to blockquotes, you'll see that it does the text with the --- underneath it, so it's not a bug.

Comment: @Ollie I'm not sure what you mean, putting an `<h1>` tag does create strange spacing in spoilers- the spacing I'm referring to is above the heading itself. It creates lots of unnecessary extra space above the heading text inside the spoiler box, which doesn't happen in blockquotes.

Comment: @zcoop98 Sorry, it does create weird spacing - but that's because of the === and --- (I've been testing this in my About Me, so I'm not sure about accuracy).  Although the whitespace (grayspace?) *above* the text does seem odd.